# Mapbox countries supported feature types list

Tags: mapbox, openstreetmap, geocoding, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

Is there a list for Mapbox geocoding, listing countries and what granularity of features they support?

i.e address, region etc

I am creating an autocomplete address form and need to determine whether i need a manual input for a given country.

There isn't any mention of this in any of the Mapbox documentation, only 1 question on here asking for it but with no answers from years ago and i haven't received a reply yet from MapBox support.

I would look for this data from say, Openstreetmaps, but Mapbox uses their own proprietary map data as well.